# How do I disable ANSI colours in Rails Console output

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I connect to a rails console using:

`bundle exec rails c`

I use enter this option in an attempt to disable ANSI colours:

```
irb(main):005:0> ActiveSupport::LogSubscriber.colorize_logging = false
=> false
```

I still see colours when I look at command outputs.

I use enter this option in an attempt to disable ANSI colours:

```
irb(main):006:0> IRB.conf[:USE_COLORIZE] = false
=> false
```

I still see colours when I look at command outputs.

I don't have permission to change any configuration files or install any Gems.

**Full Background**

I just want to run some commands to look at data objects via a script and capture the output. I don't want my file to have ANSI colour codes. I am actually doing this from my local mac using kubectl to connect to a pod where rails is running:

```
kubectl exec my-cool-pod-name -n my-cool-namespace-name -it -- bash -c "bundle exec rails c<<ENDRAILS
ActiveSupport::LogSubscriber.colorize_logging = false
myStuff = MyPkg::MyStuff.friendly.find("dog1")
myStuff.goodStuff
ENDRAILS
" > railsConsole.out
```

A work around seems to be to use the the `y` or `j` format specifiers to generate `yaml` or `json` respectively like this, but I don't really like these formats for these objects:

```
y myStuff.goodStuff
j myStuff.goodStuff.inspect
```

I also considered removing the ANSI colour codes from out redirection output file `railsConsole.out` after it has been generated, but that seems messy and unreliable from looking at posts on that technique.

Rails is version 7.0.4

```
irb(main):007:0> Rails.version
=> "7.0.4"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, the `IRB.conf[:USE_COLORIZE] = false` should work (whether in the console, or in your `~/.irbrc`). There's a CLI option for this too which you could trigger with:

```
rails c -- --nocolorize
```

But I'm not sure that'll work if the IRB.conf doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, this worked, my exact syntax from the command line within the pod was "bundle exec rails c -- --nocolorize"

Comment: Yeah perfect (sorry, I have `./bin` in my PATH so I pick up the `bin/rails` executable).